# In rare occasions SQS Listener is picking the same message twice

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

is there anyone who had a similar issue that the SQS Listener is picking the same message twice.

Scenario:

1. I send the SQS message on the queue
2. I receive that message in **javax.jms.Message** format
3. I process the message
4. I acknowledge the message

In most cases, the **acknowledge** function works just fine and it deletes the message but there are cases where the listener is picking that message twice in a row...

My question would be, is there some way I can make sure that the message won't be picked twice?

Comment: I'm using the Standard queue, not the FIFO. The option where I create the custom list where I would keep the message ids and check the duplicates in that way would probably work, but I'm looking for a better solution if there is one... Thanks

Comment: You're options are to keep a list and check for duplicates, or code your application in a way that it just doesn't care if duplicate messages are processed (idempotence), or switch to a FIFO queue.